# Recreating a sentence and outputting all the words in the sentence

Tags: python, string

> Develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list.
> For example, the sentence
>
> ```
> MY NAME IS MY NAME IS MY NAME IS
> ```
>
> The sentence can be recreated from the positions of these words in this list using the sequence 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3

This is what I have so far:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence that you would like to recreate")
x = sentence.split()

positions = [0]

for count, i in enumerate(a):
    if x.count(i) < 2:
        positions.append(max(positions) + 1)
    else:
        positions.append(x.index(i) +1)

positions.remove(0)
print(positions)
```

This recreates the positions but what I need to do is output all the words that are in the sentence.

For example, if I wrote the sentence `Leicester city are champions of the premier league the premier league is the best`, I would want the program to output that the sentence contains the words `Leicester, city, are, champions, of, the, premier, league, is, best`.

Can somebody help me in this last bit?

Comment: This question has the problem statement, code, desired output and the question itself. Good post, @Musa, this is (almost) what we expect from new users, cheers!

Comment: `print(", ".join(x))` would print the contents of the list `x` with commas and a space in between every word - is that what you're after?

Comment: Your example does not work. What is `a`?

Comment: sorry the a was meant to be the x

Answer (score 0):

Using the positions you generated, you can grab the parts of the list you want with a list comprehension or a simple for loop. The key here that while the numbers you are storing begin with `1`, python indices start at `0`. You can then use the `join` function of strings to print with commas.

```
sentence = "Leicester city are champions of the premier league the premier league is the best"
x = sentence.split()

positions = [0]

for count, i in enumerate(x):
    if x.count(i) < 2:
        positions.append(max(positions) + 1)
    else:
        positions.append(x.index(i) +1)


positions.remove(0)

reconstructed = [x[i - 1] for i in positions]
print(", ".join(reconstructed))
```

Alternatively, with a for loop:

```
reconstructed = []
for i in positions:
    reconstructed.append(x[i - 1])
```

Comment: what I was wanting was that when you output all the words in the sentence I didn't want it to say the same word rwice.

Comment: For example, if the sentence was "my name is musa hello my name is musa

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to your original algorithm or posed question, but if you want only unique words look in to using the `set` primitive. Sets do not maintain order, so you would want to use something like this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set